# Current Digital Signature Standards as of late 2023

Tags: signature, ed25519, standards

Is my summary understanding of current (classical) Digital signature standards essentially correct? I may be totally wrong.

DSA is no longer to be used for new signature generation just for checking existing signatures.

EdDSA is to be used for new signature generation.

**Question:** *Does this mean all (most?) current standardized digital signatures for generating new signatures are Elliptic curve based?*

Any caveats, explanations, extra background appreciated.

Comment: Post-quantum signature? [For digital signatures, often used when we need to verify identities during a digital transaction or to sign a document remotely, NIST has selected the three algorithms CRYSTALS-Dilithium, FALCON, and SPHINCS+ (read as “Sphincs plus”).](https://www.nist.gov/news-events/news/2022/07/nist-announces-first-four-quantum-resistant-cryptographic-algorithms)

Comment: @kelalaka, I knew I was missing something basic in problem statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A short answer on NIST;

With the [NIST.FIPS.186-5](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-5.pdf)

- Published: February 3, 2023
- Effective: February 3, 2023

> 4. Prior versions of this standard specified the DSA. **This standard no longer approves the DSA for digital signature generation.** However, **the DSA may be used to verify signatures generated prior to the implementation date of this standard**. See FIPS 186-4 [7] for the specifications for the
>    DSA.

5. The RSA Digital Signature Algorithmm : **still exists**
6. The Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)
7. The Edwards-Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (EdDSA)

Extra

- [RSA-PSS exists in TLS 1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446)

Comment: RSA still has advantages: speed and simplicity of verification, which are useful in code signing and certificates, where it is very common (certificates for EdDSA keys can be RSA-signed by a certification authority). It's justified in applications where we sign once, verify many times. It can also have low size overhead when used with message recovery, and thus ISO/IEC 9796-2 is common in Smart Cards.

Comment: Thank you @fgrieu, that's very useful.

Comment: For RSA and others, batch verification exists with problems. Also, [deterministic ECDSA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979) is also used in crypto currencies.

Comment: Batch verification is a feature of EdDSA (and possibly ECDSA and variants). I have not heard of batch verification for RSA, which verification is so fast that I do not see that batch verification is needed. @kelalaka

Comment: @fgrieu https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265585198_A_batch_verifying_and_detecting_multiple_RSA_digital_signatures

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The RSA batch verification scheme in [this article](https://isrc.asia.edu.tw/www/myjournal/P050.pdf) and it's [Harn reference](https://h.web.umkc.edu/harnl/papers/1998%20J2.pdf) is applicable only to some RSA signatures standards that hash-then-textbook-RSA-sign (e.g. RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5, RSA-FDH, not RSASSA-PSS), and only for multiple messages signed with the same key. This limits it's applications. When it applies, it does save some computation, appreciably so for very large $e$.

Comment: @fgrieu OK, thank you for distinguishing those. I did not look that deep and I should have.